# M2Doc General Questions

Tags: filtering, enterprise-architect, m2doc

I have two general questions regarding M2Doc:

1. Does M2Doc also work for other (than Capella) modelling SW? Do you have experience with Enterprise Architect?
2. When exporting tables with model parameters from the model into a Word document, is it possible to generate a template that automatically filters the parameters? For example, in case tables containing only input or output parameters are desired.

Comment: You better ask that at github where you got that from.

Answer (score 2):

1. M2Doc support all [EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) models but as far as I know Enterprise Architect use an other format. If you are looking for an EA solution based on EMF you can have a look at [SmartEA](https://www.obeosmartea.com).
2. I lack context here but:

   - If you are using a Sirius representation you can change it or create a new one with the needed filter
   - if the table is created in a M2Doc for statement you can filter elements from the for loop.
   - if none on this you can create your own [service](http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#providing-new-services) that return a [MTable](http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#special-return-types) constructed from Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm : you can use M2DOC with SmartEA since version 3.1